# Can I use CMS to design css styles and header/footer and leave the content implementation empty to be designed/developed by developers?

Tags: web-applications, content-management-system, web-application-design

We have requirement to employ a CMS for brochureware/marketing websites. But we are thinking to allow content designers to design look and feel of the ecommerce pages in CMS and then leave the content implementation (e.g. jquery/ajax etc) to the developers. Is it possible with a CMS?
We use enterprise java but we are open to any 'easy to use cms' as long as it flushes out the content into a db?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that, if you are not dealing with user defined content, then CMS is only going to add overheads.

For styling the look and feel, consider using custom themes, or better a front-end framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/), to have look and feel set.

Then you could plug in any application to push/pull content. You don't need a CMS just for defining themes.